# File.Copy - DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled

Tags: c#, file, copy

When I use this code it doesn't throw any errors but it still doesn't copy anything. Any ideas?.

```
 //string spath = string.Format("S:\\ 0A36303 / user:admin");
                DateTime theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
                DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo("S:");
                string dircreate = string.Format(@"N:\{0:MM-dd-yyyy}\" + label1.Text + "LogFiles", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date, label1.Text);
                DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(dircreate);


                FileInfo[] fis = Dir.GetFiles( ".txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
                {
                    if (fi.LastWriteTime.Date == theDate)
                    {
                        File.Copy(fi.FullName, target.FullName + @"\" + fi.Name, true);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that S:\pc.log exists

Comment: Yes the file exists, but the file is actually named pchost.txt and pcaudit.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full UNC path to access the file:

```
DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\\share\\pathtofile");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems come to mind:

1. The `S:\PC.log` file doesn't exist => you cannot copy non-existent file
2. The process you are executing your code under doesn't have read permission to the specified folder (`S:`). Looks like a network share. If you are running this code inside an ASP.NET application the process probably doesn't have read permissions to this remote share => you cannot copy a file that you don't have permissions to access.

Comment: I put in the admin credentials whenever I mapped the drive, is it possible that I will also need the creds at copy time?

Comment: Are you running this code inside an ASP.NET application? If so, make sure you have granted sufficient privileges to the account you have configured your application to run under.

Comment: So then does the `S:\PC.log` file exist when you run this code?